# Show Categorie(s) of a post in a list of custom posts

Tags: wordpress, show, categories, posts

I've searched this question a lot, but all I find is answers of how to show every category for a specific taxonomy.

I'm developing a theme, and I'm going to filter a list of posts (custom post type 'jobs') using jQuery, but I need to have a `<div>` with a class showing the categories of that specific post.

I'm going to filter these on the category page (jobs).

For this to work, I'm putting all my code in the loop.php.

```
<div class="post_entry">
        <div class="post-thumb"><?php the_post_thumbnail('single-post-thumbnail'); ?></div>
        <h4 class="post-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( '%s', 'twentyten' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
        <?php   
            $location = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'location', TRUE);
            $organization = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'organization', TRUE);
            $url = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'url', TRUE); 
        ?>
        <div class="post-meta">
            <?php if($organization != ''){ ?><p class="post_meta_organization"><?php echo $organization; ?></p><?php } ?>
            <?php if($location != ''){ ?><p class="post_meta_location"><?php echo $location; ?></p><?php } ?>
            <?php if($url != ''){ ?><p class="post_meta_url">Website: <a href="<?php echo $url; ?>">Click Here</a></p><?php } ?>
        </div>
        <div class="hidden tags">

        </div>


<?php if ( is_archive() || is_search() ) : // Only display excerpts for archives and search. ?>
        <p class="post_excerpt"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
<?php else : ?>
        <div class="category_read_more"><?php the_content( __( 'Read More', 'twentyten' ) ); ?></div>
        <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '' . __( 'Pages:', 'twentyten' ), 'after' => '' ) ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
            <?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'twentyten' ), '', '' ); ?>

    <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>
    </div>
```

I've been lucky to add meta-box information, but I want to show the posts custom categories (jobtype) in `<div class="hidden tags"></div>`

To take a look at the website, check out http://www.cirkut.net/wp/libertyguide/jobs

If anyone could help, that would be fantastic!  If any more information is needed, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

In the loop:

```
Category: <?php echo get_the_category_list(', '); ?>
```

Update:

Wordpress writes:

> Listing the terms
>
> If you want to have a custom list in your theme, then you can pass the
>   taxonomy name into the the_terms() function in the Loop, like so:
>
> the_terms( $post->ID, 'people', 'People: ', ', ', ' ' );

This should address your problem.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies#Listing_the_terms

Comment: This doesn't work.  I'm using a custom taxonomy.  To clarify a bit more, I need the categories to be shown in a space separated list (e.g. 'web-dev career full-time' instead of 'web/dev, career, full-time)

Comment: I have updated the answer. Hope this in now what you are looking for.